# Confirming expected value of decision tree depth via resampling in Python

Tags: python, decision-tree

I'm trying to confirm the answer to question 1., chapter 6, of *Hands-on Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn, Keras & TensorFlow* by Aurélian Géron.

> C61. What is the approximate depth of a Decision Tree trained (without restrictions) on a training set with one million instances?"

Via its solutions, the book derives an answer of 19.93.

I want to reproduce this via resampling in Python.  The resulting graph suggests 20 is not the correct answer.  In fact, if I change the range of the `randint` function when defining `X`, the distribution looks different.   I am assuming I'm not doing something correctly.

What am I doing wrong?  The claim "without restrictions" suggests to me reproduction should not be difficult.  Is it because I'm resampling each iterate?  Is it because this is a regression tree, and not classification?  Is it some other dumb thing with my code?

Note that I'm using `multiprocess` in lieu of `multiprocessing` because my Python runs via Anaconda.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import multiprocess as mp2 

# Define fitting function. 
def random_dt(k): 
    X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size = (1000000, 2)), columns = ['y', 'x'])
    y = X['y'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
    X = X['x'].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1)
    dt = DecisionTreeRegressor()
    dt.fit(X, y)
    depth = dt.get_depth()
    return(depth)

# Speed this along.
p = mp2.Pool(processes = mp2.cpu_count() - 1)
with p as mp_pool: 
    depths = mp_pool.map(random_dt, range(10000))

# See distribution of depths. 
a = min(depths)
b = max(depths)
plt.hist(depths, bins = np.arange(a - 0.5, b + 0.5))
plt.xticks(range(a, b))
plt.xlabel('Depth')
plt.ylabel('Models N')
plt.title('Distribution of $N = 10,000$ Decision-Tree Depths')
plt.xlim()
plt.show()
```

While the distribution is slightly right-skewed, its mean and median are 17.14 and 17, respectively.  (So, not close to 20.)  A subsequent run with 100,000 (not shown) did not change these results.

[image: Distribution of Depth over 10,000 Decision Trees]

Answer (score 0):

The depth of a well-balanced binary tree containing m leaves is equal to log2(m)³, rounded up. A binary Decision Tree (one that makes only binary decisions, as is the case of all trees in Scikit-Learn) will end up more or less well balanced at the end of training, with one leaf per training instance if it is trained without restrictions. Thus, if the training set contains one million instances, the Decision Tree will have a depth of log2(10⁶) ≈ 20 (actually a bit more since the tree will generally not be perfectly well balanced).

Source: https://rachelchen0104.medium.com/6-decision-trees-hands-on-ml-f0822ee43219